# Improving speed and accuracy of a model by reducing classes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am experimenting on different pre-trained models from Tensorflow Model Zoo for a real-time object detection problem.
I am running the inference on CPU and the performance (fps, mAP) is sub-par. While I understand why models trade-off accuracy for speed, or vice-versa, I was wondering if the number of classes that a model has to detect has a linear relationship to its performance.
Most of the pre-trained models can detect 80+ objects and I need just a subset of those classes for my problem. Basically, if I do transfer learning on a model that detects 80 objects to lets say, just 5 objects, can the model run faster?

Answer (score 0):

In Theory, yes.
In practise, rather not.
The speed of a model is determined (with others) by its amount of parameters. When you only need to predict 5 instead of 80 classes, you need less parameters, in theory.

In practise, the model learned the properties of the classes in all its parameters. You would need to decide, which weights you want to use and which not. For sure this is possible somehow by detecting which weight has which influence on the final prediction.
You could for example write a custom loss function, that only creates a loss for certain class predictions, but then you would need to adjust the gradient in such a way, that its setting weights, that are only used for other predictions, to zero.

And before you do that, you rather want to simply use a smaller model or create one model by yourself.

**Update**

WHAT you could do is to improve it atleast a little bit. Softmax is a computational intense activation function, so reducing the weights of the last layer might already improve the speed a bit. So use all layers of the model, except the last one and replace it with a softmax layer with 5 neurons (for each class 1). That would atleast reduce the weights in the output layer and might already speed up inference